# Asp.net Update GridView with AutoGenerateEditButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, insert

How do I use the AutoGenerateEditButton to update my gridview Table (has a dataset bound to it -Dataset Retrieved from an sql database)

[image]

--Removed the Broken code in the question to put Fixed code in the Answer--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the values of the updated row add this to your "RowUpdating" event handler

protected void grdViewDetails_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {

```
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)grdViewDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        foreach (Control item in row.Controls)
        {
            if (item.Controls[0] is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox textbox = (TextBox)item.Controls[0];
                string x = textbox.Text; //theres your value you can do stuff with
            }
            if (item.Controls[0] is Label)
            {
                Label mylabel = (Label)item;
                //do stuff - just do the same as the textbox
            }
        }
```

}

and in "RowEditing" event handler

```
 protected void grdViewDetails_RowEditing1(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            grdViewDetails.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            //e.newedit index:- will be provide index of row for which edit button is selected
            grdViewDetails.DataSource = yourdatasource //mine was a datset
            grdViewDetails.DataBind();
        }
```